# Confusing MySQL Explain Results

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm currently trying to figure out which query is actually making better use of indexes, and which will be faster (those two things don't always coincide).

I've run the same query twice, but with the index columns shuffled around to maximize performance.

`INDEX(type, finalized_on, user_id, date_applied)`

```
mysql> explain 
select user_id
     , sum(amount) amount 
  from user_accounts_payable force index (type_date_finalized_user) 
 where type=1 
   and date_applied between '2018-01-01' and '2019-01-01' 
   and finalized_on is null 
 group 
  by user_id;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type | possible_keys                                                              | key                      | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_accounts_payable | ref  | type_user_date_finalized,type_user_finalized_date,type_date_finalized_user | type_date_finalized_user | 10      | const,const | 59720 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+-------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Now with `INDEX(type, finalized_on, date_applied, user_id)`

```
mysql> explain select user_id, sum(amount) amount from user_accounts_payable force index (type_date_finalized_user) where type=1 and date_applied between '2018-01-01' and '2019-01-01' and finalized_on is null group by user_id;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type  | possible_keys                                                              | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_accounts_payable | range | type_user_date_finalized,type_user_finalized_date,type_date_finalized_user | type_date_finalized_user | 13      | NULL | 3243 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

The second query clearly uses more of the index as I can see with the `key_len` (13 vs 10), and the number of `rows` it matches is less (3243 vs 59720).

What's throwing me off is the `type`, `ref` and `extra` columns of the `EXPLAIN`.

In the second query I'm seeing a "Using temporary; Using filesort" which isn't present in the first query. The `type` is `range` instead of `ref` (`ref` is supposed to be faster than `range`), and the `ref` column is `NULL` instead of `const,const`.

So...  which is making better use of the index?

Comment: Could you specify what you consider "better use of index" (if performance is not a measure for it)? Indexes (other than indexes used for constraints like unique, pk or foreign keys) are created to improve the performance, otherwise they would just use storage space/memory for no benefit. The filesort in the 2nd case is needed because of the group by (to put all rows for the same user together; in the first query, those are already grouped/sorted together because of the index, but these also include unwanted `date_applied`-values (so more rows, and some have to be skipped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first was able to use the index for the `GROUP BY user_id`, thereby avoiding the sort (tmp+filesort).  However, it had to skip over any rows with the dates not in the range, hence a larger Rows.

The second used the date range, hence fewer rows, but then had to do the sort.

If you had both indexes, *and* did not use `FORCE INDEX`, the Optimizer *might* have picked the better index dynamically, based on the specific date range.  (But I doubt it.)  In any case, your query is a case where the Optimizer simply does not have enough statistics to always "do the right thing".

Please note that "Using temporary; Using filesort" is *often* a fast, simple, qsort in RAM -- no temp table, no disk hits.  (I say this to remind readers not to fear that phrase.

If you tack `amount` onto the *end* of either index, you will get "Using index", which means it is a "covering" index, which will run (very roughly) twice as fast.

"Using index condition" is unrelated; it means that the Engine did some of the evaluation of the `WHERE`.

Comment: I was about to answer too, but this is already complete. Great answer!

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. In the second query, the user_id data is grouped together after the range scan, I assume that means the filesort ends up being very fast since the data is basically already sorted, no?